# Disabling automatic updates to QGIS

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I previously had Prizren installed and a few weeks ago it updated to Maidenhead

I need to use an incredibly niche plugin whose development I have no control over. Getting it working on Prizren was hard enough, and getting it working on Maidenhead was more difficult. I'm worried that a future update will make it impossible to use this plugin, and wish to prevent that

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but unfortunately googling for this problem returns a lot of results to do with updating data in a current QGIS project which isn't relevant to what I want.

I can see in the Ubuntu update logs the following entry for late February, which is approximately when the update would have occurred. The line "Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'" makes it look like something I did, but there is nothing in the command history that looks like a plausible cause. I guess attempting to figure out what "Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'" is a question for the Ubuntu boards

---

It turns out (on Ubuntu anyway) that the OS can perform automatic updates. I have temporarily disabled qgis updates via this mechanism using this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772900/help-interpreting-commandline-packagekit-role-update-packages/772904#772904

```
Start-Date: 2024-02-26  19:09:09
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Install: libqgisgrass7-3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic), 
python3-pyqt5.qtserialport:amd64 (5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3, automatic), 
libqgis-gui3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic), 
libqgis-server3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic),
libqgis-native3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic),
linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-21-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1, automatic),
libqgis-app3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic),
libqgis-core3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic),
linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1, automatic),
linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-21:amd64 (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1, automatic),
linux-modules-6.5.0-21-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1, automatic),
libqgis-analysis3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic), 
linux-image-6.5.0-21-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1, automatic),
libqgispython3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic), 
libqgis-3d3.36.0:amd64 (1:3.36.0+36jammy, automatic)

Upgrade: tcpdump:amd64 (4.99.1-3ubuntu0.1, 4.99.1-3ubuntu0.2), 
libxtables12:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), 
coreutils:amd64 (8.32-4.1ubuntu1, 8.32-4.1ubuntu1.1), 
iptables:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), 
libglx-mesa0:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:22.04.17, 1:22.04.19), 
language-pack-en-base:amd64 (1:22.04+20230801, 1:22.04+20240212), 
qgis-common:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
libgbm1:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
libgdm1:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.4), 
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:22.04.17, 1:22.04.19), 
qgis-plugin-grass:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
firmware-sof-signed:amd64 (2.0-1ubuntu4.4, 2.0-1ubuntu4.5), 
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.17.17~22.04.9, 6.5.0.21.21~22.04.11), 
libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), 
python3-qgis:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
tracker-miner-fs:amd64 (3.3.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 3.3.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2),
python3-qgis-common:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
qgis:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
language-pack-en:amd64 (1:22.04+20230801, 1:22.04+20240212), 
language-pack-gnome-en-base:amd64 (1:22.04+20230801, 1:22.04+20240212), 
libxatracker2:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
python-apt-common:amd64 (2.4.0ubuntu2, 2.4.0ubuntu3), 
mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
libqgis-customwidgets:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
qgis-providers-common:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
gdm3:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.4), 
qgis-providers:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2),
base-files:amd64 (12ubuntu4.5, 12ubuntu4.6), 
python3-apt:amd64 (2.4.0ubuntu2, 2.4.0ubuntu3), 
login:amd64 (1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1, 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.2), 
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.17.17~22.04.9, 6.5.0.21.21~22.04.11),
linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.17.17~22.04.9, 6.5.0.21.21~22.04.11),
tracker-extract:amd64 (3.3.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 3.3.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2),
libip6tc2:amd64 (1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1, 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.2), 
gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.4), 
libglapi-mesa:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
qgis-plugin-grass-common:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
qgis-provider-grass:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
language-pack-gnome-en:amd64 (1:22.04+20230801, 1:22.04+20240212), 
code:amd64 (1.86.1-1707298119, 1.86.2-1707854558), 
unzip:amd64 (6.0-26ubuntu3.1, 6.0-26ubuntu3.2), 
libegl-mesa0:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2), 
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:22.04.17, 1:22.04.19), 
python-qgis:amd64 (1:3.34.3+36jammy, 1:3.36.0+36jammy), 
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1, 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2),
dns-root-data:amd64 (2021011101, 2023112702~ubuntu0.22.04.1), 
passwd:amd64 (1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1, 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.2), 
linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-94.104, 5.15.0-97.107)

End-Date: 2024-02-26  19:10:07
```

Comment: As far as I know, QGIS doesn't auto update itself.

Comment: Can you provide what error messages you are getting?   @John is correct there is not an automatic update.  Are you referring to the plugin update?

Comment: Possibly leave more information about the issue with the update (wht plugin and what error).  It did not happen automatically.

Comment: Hi, @John the startup splash used to say Prizren, now it says Maidenhead. I was very surprised because qgis doesn't seem like the kind of installation that happens automatically.

Comment: @BERA Operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Comment: @CaryH, I am not talking about the plugin, I am talking about QGIS. Error message not really relevant, because my question is about preventing future updates and not about fixing the current problem (which I already did).

Comment: Thanks all, I get this is a weird question, but this is what happened to me. I absolutely did not intentionally update QGIS because getting it working the first time was hard enough

Comment: I dont know if this is correct but maybe something like this is possible, to prevent qgis from updating when you update other packages: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Comment: Never again being able to update QGIS is probably a bad idea.

So, although you say you have no control over the plugin, it might be best to ask the developers of said plugin to update it accordingly. This may or may not be possible, and may or may not be successful. You can probably nudge these developers a bit in the right direction by paying them for doing the work. Depending on the license of the plugin, you may well also be able to pay anyone else to develop the plugin.